# PCAPNG file that does not send packets through TCPReplay

Tags: linux, networking, udp, tcpreplay

Using tcpreplay I am able to send UDP packets from a pcapng file (Log.pcapng) on a linux machine using:

```
sudo tcpreplay --intf1=enp9s0 --loop=10 log.pcapng
```

Using Wireshark on a second Windows 10 machine I can see that the UDP packets are arriving.

When I try the same thing using a different pcapng file (orientation_fix.pcapng) I do not get any UDP packets arriving on the second machine.

I've tried setting the destination mac address to broadcast using tcpwrite (orientation_fix_broadcast.pcapng) but it still does not cause any UDP packets to arrive.

The only difference I can see between the packets in the 2 files is that the working file (log.pcapng) has an entry for Interface Id in the Frame section.

I've attached links to the files on my GoogleDrive below:

- [Log.pcapng](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SquDpmm4f77hNZxuLHN7jWw7spNlXTp1)
- [orientation_fix.pcapng](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fp1eFx2r_FtrHwW6CG6EYs3xuglHbuTV)
- [orientation_fix_broadcast.pcapng](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KzBUOGiKDyqKnnPacxpFXc1-wmUsKRk2)

How can I get the orientation_fix.pcapng file to send the UDP packets it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the source mac address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to something else. I used:

```
--enet-smac=d4:81:d7:04:c8:c9
```

This can be used in tcprewrite to modify the file, or as an argument in tcpreplay-edit to make the change on the fly